# Modify View Controller Properties Before View Controller is Displayed

Tags: ios, swift, layout, autolayout, viewcontroller

I'm about to finish my first iOS app, but I'm facing a problem that I don't know how to solve.

The initial ViewController of the app contains a MKMapView, that has few annotations. When clicking any annotation, a popup appears with some info and then, there's an info button that leads to a new ViewController, with detailed information related to the selected annotation.

The thing is that second ViewController(DetailedViewController), has few labels (title, description), an image and few links, which should be loaded before the ViewController itself is shown. I'm reading this values from a JSON but there's no problem with that.

I'm reading all values and setting them in the ViewDidLoad()

So the thing is, when that second ViewController(DetailedViewController) is loaded in the simulator or in the physical iPhone, all fields has their default value (the one set in the storyboard) and spends few seconds to update with the desired values, even they're read so fast from the JSON (according to logs).

Also, an error appears in the console:

```
This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.
 Stack:(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018a0ca1d8 <redacted> + 148
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000188b0455c objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018a0ca108 <redacted> + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x000000018acb1ea4 <redacted> + 192
    4   Foundation                          0x000000018acb1be4 <redacted> + 76
    5   Foundation                          0x000000018aafd54c <redacted> + 112
    6   Foundation                          0x000000018acb0880 <redacted> + 112
    7   UIKit                               0x000000018ff2140c <redacted> + 1688
    8   QuartzCore                          0x000000018d3e1188 <redacted> + 148
    9   UIKit                               0x000000019056de90 <redacted> + 64
    10  QuartzCore                          0x000000018d3d5e64 <redacted> + 292
    11  QuartzCore                          0x000000018d3d5d24 <redacted> + 32
    12  QuartzCore                          0x000000018d3527ec <redacted> + 252
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000018d379c58 <redacted> + 512
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000018d37a124 <redacted> + 660
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018915efbc <redacted> + 572
    16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018915ece4 <redacted> + 200
    17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018915e378 pthread_mutex_lock + 0
    18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018915dda4 start_wqthread + 4
)
```

I've read similar issues and they're talking about something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(){
    // code here
})
```

But I don't know exactly how to use it :(

Can anybody help me?

Thank you very much in advance :)

EDIT:

I'll add the code of my detailed view controller, to explain more accurately what happens:

```
class BarDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var BarDetailsView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var BarNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var BarDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var BarImage: UIImageView!

var barPhoneNumber: AnyObject! = "anyBarPhoneNumber"
var barWebsite: AnyObject! = "anyBarWebsite"
var barName: AnyObject! = "anyBarName"

var pinCoordinates : CLLocationCoordinate2D!
var pinId : String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let jsonURL: String = "http://www.craftbr.me/services/getbiz/index.php?barid=" + self.pinId
    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: jsonURL)!

    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        if (statusCode == 200) {
            do{
                let json: AnyObject! = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

                let barName: AnyObject! = json["name"]
                self.BarNameLabel.text = String(barName)
                self.barName = String(barName)

                self.BarDescriptionLabel.text = (json["description"] as! String)

                self.barPhoneNumber = json["telf"]

                self.barWebsite = json["website"] as! String

                let barImgUrl: AnyObject! = json["imgurl"]
                let barImgUrlString: String! = String(barImgUrl)

                if let imageUrl  = NSURL(string: barImgUrlString),
                    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl)
                {
                    self.BarImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }

            }catch {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }  
    task.resume()
}

}
```

So here, inside of the ViewDidLoad() I modify the labels content created in the Storyboard with the info got from the json.

The thing is getting the info from the json is so fast, but then, modifying the labels is the thing that is slow and throws the error.

So @fragilecat, where should I add the function? And how do I declare the DispatchQueue? I've tried it but it doesn't work. And this function, where should be called?

Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Check out the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple uses queues to represent threads, as @Adam says in the comments you you should look at [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to get a better understanding of your app's behavior.

However it might be useful to explain what is going on with your app that it creates your crash as it is a very common pattern in iOS.

You are making a request to some web service. Unless explicitly this reuqest is going to happen on a background queue. If this was not the case your app's UI would freeze while the request to the web service was made. The point to remember here is that ALL ui work must be done on the main queue! @Leon Guo has shown you how to access the main queue from a different queue.

So how does this effect your web service request. Well when the response comes back and you parse it and you are ready to assign the data to ui elements such as labels and textfields, you want to do that on the main queue like so:

```
// comment: example method on DetailedViewController class
func prepareUI(data: MyDataType){
    // Swift 3
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        titleLabel.text = data.titleString
        descriptionLabel.text = data.descriptionText
    }
}
```

Or other wise you will be accessing the ui elements in the DetailedViewController from a queue other than the main queue, hence your crash. So to solve your problem right now wrap your assign of the UI elements in the `DispatchQueue.main.async` block of code where ever you are doing it. This should get you back up and running again.

In the long term you need to develop an understanding of how concurrency is implemented in iOS. [The App Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072) is a great place to start!

**Edit**

Here is your code using the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` function. I would state that this is just to get you up and running...

```
import UIKit

class BarDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var barDetailsView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var barNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var barDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var BarImage: UIImageView!

    var barPhoneNumber  = "anyBarPhoneNumber"
    var barWebsite = "anyBarWebsite"
    var barName = "anyBarName"

    var pinCoordinates : CLLocationCoordinate2D!
    var pinId : String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // For example purposes only
        networkCall()

    }



    func networkCall() {
        let jsonURL: String = "http://www.craftbr.me/services/getbiz/index.php?barid=" + self.pinId
        let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: jsonURL)!

        let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

            let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                do{

                    let json: AnyObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

                    // Here we get back on the main queue since we are altering UI elements
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        let barName: AnyObject! = json["name"]
                        self.barNameLabel.text = String(barName)
                        self.barName = String(barName)

                        if let text = json["description"] as? String {
                            self.barDescriptionLabel.text = text
                        }

                        if phoneNumber = json["telf"] as? String {
                            self.barPhoneNumber = phoneNumber
                        }

                        if webSite = json["website"] as? String {
                            self.barWebsite =  barWebsite
                        }

                        let barImgUrl: AnyObject = json["imgurl"]
                        let barImgUrlString: String = String(barImgUrl)

                        if let imageUrl  = NSURL(string: barImgUrlString), let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl) {
                            self.BarImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
                        }
                    }


                }catch {
                    print("Error with Json: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've edited the post adding more info. Where should I call this function? And how do I declare the DispatchQueue? I've tried it but I cannot make it work :(

Comment: I will take a look at it.

Comment: Here take a look now.

Comment: Hello again. Thanks, with your piece of code my understanding of how it works has improved :) I've replied the structure to my code, understanding how it works, but in the line where we call the DispatchQueue: `DispatchQueue.main.async {` appears an error saying _**Use of unresolved identifier 'DispatchQueue'**_. Reading posts with that same error, I've added an the Import Dispatch to the top of my swift file, so now, I have the following ones `Import Foundation Import UIKit Import MapKit Import Dispatch`. But the error still appears, it cannot resolve the DispatchQueue. Something wrong? Thx

Comment: Do you know what version of Swift your using?

Comment: Yes! That was the problem! I've modified it and now it works perfectly :D Thanks a lot for your help in my first iOS app and in the understanding of the behaviour of Swift :) Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

All updating operations about UI must be done in the main thread, such as modifying the background of a view in the view controller, you can do like the following:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
```

Comment: GCD API had some changes in Swift 3.0

Comment: First of all, thanks for your quick answer :)

Forgive me for my ignorance, but I'm not so experienced in iOS developing and I'm a little bit confused.

When you're talking about the main thread, you mean that I should put this code in the DetailedViewController, but outside the ViewDidLoad function? And how do I declare the DispatchQueue?

Thanks again for you help :)